# Move JS in between head tags

Tags: jquery, append, head

I am using this web design app, and for some reason it puts the JS (look below) in between the `<body>` tags and not in the head tags.

So is there any way to get this code into the HEAD tags using some form of JS?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').rollbar({zIndex:100});
  });
</script>
```

The reason for this is, I want the jQuery plugin to apply to the 'body' div, but it doesn't work if it's in the BODY tags - but it does when it's in the HEAD tags. 
If there is anyway to dynamically move the code from the body tags to the HEAD tags that would be awesome. I've been wanting to know how/and if that's possible for a while now

Look forward to the responses!

Comment: You can't just edit the code and move it yourself?

Comment: I could, but then it takes away the use of this program. Is there any way to move it? If there is I'd be willing to pay someone to help me out.

Comment: It's legal to have script tags in the body.

Comment: Sime, true, but the plugin acts weird when its between the BODY tags.

Comment: As long as JQuery is above anything with $ it should work fine.

Comment: Would it help if I gave you a link to a site showing the issue? Doesn't work when it's between BODY tags, at all.

Comment: I think it's because the effect is being applied to the BODY tag.

Comment: What is it doing to the body tag?

Comment: It's a scrollbar custom plugin, that replaces the browser default scrollbar, in order to do that it has to target the body tag.

Comment: I would link it. This sounds like an awful plug-in.

Comment: @Airman that sounds like a horrible idea.  Browsers provide a perfectly good scrollbar already.

Comment: Please link us to your website.

Comment: Airman, I think you're going about this the wrong way. Instead of asking "How do I move the script?", you should be asking "What stops the script working where it is?" - because (like everyone else said) from the limited code you show it should work the same in either place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').rollbar({zIndex:100});
  });
</script>
```

will work identically whether it's in the HEAD section or the BODY section as long as jQuery is loaded before it.  That's because the `$(document).ready` causes the `$('body').rollbar({zIndex:100});` not to execute until after the document is loaded which will be the same time no matter where the original code was loaded from.

If you are seeing a difference in behavior when you move it, then something else is causing that difference that you have not disclosed because simply moving this code to the HEAD section will not cause a difference (as long as jQuery is already loaded).

Answer (score 0):

No.  At least not on the page.  You are going to have take this up with your "web design app", whatever that is.

Javascript cannot change any part of the DOM that is not parsed.  And script tags are executed as soon as they are parsed.  So you cannot move a script tag until after it executes.  And even it you did move it, it would have run already, at which point moving it would have no real effect.

Most experienced web developers hand code all this stuff so that you have control over things like where your script tags are.  So might I suggest that maybe this "web design app" doesn't have your best interests in mind?

Comment: Thanks Alex and Erik, so I assume it isn't possible, at all?

Comment: @ErikReppen The script tag is still parsed and executed.  If that script tag happens to have code that schedules some logic for later, well thats up to whatever that code is.  But if all his code really is _all_ delayed via `$(document).ready()`, then it doesn't matter where the script tags are and this question makes no sense...

Comment: @Airman more likely the location of the script tag isn't your problem unless this plug-in is doing something really jacked like waiting for the body element to load rather than simply hit the body on document.ready which would be kind of ridiculous for a JQuery plug-in since JQ basically introduced the concept.